# Disk space in windows not representing actual qcow2 image size

Tags: rhel, windows, kvm, qemu

The disk space shown in Windows running in KVM does not represent the actual disk space available for the qcow2 disk image.

The Windows Management Console shows there is 100 GB for the drive, but only lists 30 GB for the capacity.

The QEMU/KVM manager, It shows there is 100 GB available for the disk.

[image: Windows Management Console showing discrepancy in disk space]

[image: KVM manager showing qcow2 disk space]

I'm at a loss for how to get this to expand and use the entire 100 GB that should be available to Windows. Help?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, and the fix is to type the following in an administrator command prompt, assuming `disk 0` is `C:` and `partition 2` is the partition in question.

Type "diskpart" and press Enter
Execute the following commands to extend the partition:

```
SELECT DISK 0
SELECT PARTITION 2
EXTEND FILESYSTEM
EXIT
```